# Change the value of input field without id

Tags: javascript

Can someone please help me with this?
How can I change the value of the input fields without ids?
I cannot change the input fields because I am integrating with a platform, and they can only support js. Okay, first code works to read the URL parameters.
Basically, it would autofill values into the form..

Thanks

```js
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var get_params = function(search_string) {

            var parse = function(params, pairs) {
                var pair = pairs[0];
                var parts = pair.split('=');
                var key = decodeURIComponent(parts[0]);
                var value = decodeURIComponent(parts.slice(1).join('='));

                // Handle multiple parameters of the same name
                if (typeof params[key] === "undefined") {
                    params[key] = value;
                } else {
                    params[key] = [].concat(params[key], value);
                }

                return pairs.length == 1 ? params : parse(params, pairs.slice(1))
            }

            // Get rid of leading ?
            return search_string.length == 0 ? {} : parse({}, search_string.substr(1).split('&'));
        }

        var params = get_params(location.search);

    </script>


</head>
<body>


<!-- nanacast form -->
<tbody>
    <tr id="customFieldsTR01">
        <td id="customFieldsTR01td1">           
            <span style="font-weight: bold;" id="customFieldsTR01td1SPAN1">First Name&nbsp;</span>
        </td>
        <td id="customFieldsTR02td1">
            <input type="text" name="u_firstname" value="">
            <span id="*" class="tableRequired" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="customFieldsTR11">
        <td id="customFieldsTR11td1">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;" id="customFieldsTR11td1SPAN1">Last Name&nbsp;</span>
        </td>      <td id="customFieldsTR12td1">
            <input type="text" name="u_lastname" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="customFieldsTR21">
        <td id="customFieldsTR21td1">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;" id="customFieldsTR21td1SPAN1">Email&nbsp;</span>
        </td>
        <td id="customFieldsTR22td1">
            <input type="text" name="u_email" value="">
            <span id="*" class="tableRequired" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">*</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

</body>

    <!-- not working since input fields do not have ids
    <script>
        document.getElementById("first_name").value = params['FirstName'];
        document.getElementById("last_name").value = params['LastName'];
        document.getElementById("email").value = params['EMail'];
    </script>
    -------->

</html>
```

Comment: use `querySelector()` to target required fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector()` and find them by name:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="u_firstname"]').value = 'New value'
```

Answer (score -1):

Since all the element on your code has name try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("u_firstname");
```